# Stream videos from Raspberry Pi saved on its SD card

Tags: pi-3, streaming-video, media-server

I am trying to figure out a way where I can stream the videos saved on Pi's SD card. I do not need live streaming. I only need to stream the videos which will be saved on its SD card. Is this possible? I have looked by for similar solutions online but most of them point to streaming live videos. I also tried to look up into solutions to turn the Raspberry Pi into a media server. Some of the solutions require an external hard disk connected to the Pi. Am not quite sure if this the way if I should look at. Please point out if I am wrong. Are there any options to which do not need the external drive connected to the Pi?  Additionally, I need to configure it to stream remotely and not only on the local network. Also, is it possible to stream multiple videos simultaneously? My videos won't be long, max 20 seconds recorded videos. Please point me in the correct direction. Thanks a lot for your time and effort in advance.

Comment: welcome to StackExchange! Yes, it's very possible to setup video streaming on a Raspberry Pi, directly from the SD Card. Be aware that if you constantly put videos on a SD Card, it'll die sooner or later. But aside from that, here are some options you have: a) Use a web server to expose those videos as static files. You may do this with nginx, or something like this (https://github.com/mikeckennedy/cache-tier) b) Start a FTP server c) Use VLC to do a livestream